# openacc compiler supporting nested compute constructs

Tags: openacc

I'm studying the OpenaAcc Programming guide at openacc.org. A lot of nested compute regions are widely used in this book. But my compiler (version 17.4-0 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux -tp sandybridge year 2017) writes that my version of the compiler does not support nested compute constructs. Does this version of the compiler really not support nested compute constructs? If it is so, which compiler to use if i need nested compute constructs support? Do latest versions of gcc support this option?

Answer (score 1):

Correct, PGI does not yet support nested parallelism (i.e. compute regions within other compute regions).  I don't think GNU supports it as well.

Can you point the specific section of the OpenACC programming guide you are referring?  I don't remember any nested parallelism examples and am wondering if you are meaning the addition of "loop" directives within a compute region which is supported by both compilers.

Comment: The OpenAcc Programming Guide (https://www.openacc.org/sites/default/files/inline-files/OpenACC_Programming_Guide_0.pdf). For example, pages 41, 42, 43-44, 45 contain examples of nested parallelism. Please, check me, but it seems to me I'm right.

Comment: No, those are examples of using the "loop" directive within a compute region which is fine.  Nested parallelism is when you have compute regions, "parallel" or "kernels", within another compute region.

Comment: Given this comment as well as your other posts here and on the PGI User Forum, I think you might be confused by the difference between a compute region, "parallel" or "kernels", and the "loop" directive.  A compute region defines what code to offload to the device, while a "loop" directive defines within a compute region which loops to parallelize and at which level of parallelism to use, "gang", "worker", or "vector".  Code within a compute region but not within a "loop" directive is executed redundantly by each gang.

Comment: Excuse me for misunderstanding. As far as i understood, nested parallelism means one "parallel/kernels" inside another one and "pragma acc loop" is only the directive specifying how to treat the "for" loop.